# VsCode debuger stop Suddenly in one of ASP.NET Core action

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-debugger

When I run a action in my ASP.NET Core app debugger, I get this error:

> The program  has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

My Action is this but never run in app:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RoleCUViewModel model)
{
    //Do Some thing
}
```

And My `ViewModel` is this:

```
public class RoleCUViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string? Name
    {
        get => Name;
        set
        {
            if (value != "Admin")
            {
                Name = value;
            }
            else Name = null;
        }
    }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

I delete `Authorize` attribute and test in `Action` but my problem not solved.

[image]

My IDE is VS Code and my application framework is .NET 7.0.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: We can see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to ***SHOW US*** the relevant code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message `The program has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).`, and I found it's code issue, the getter for `Name` is recursively calling itself without any exit condition, leading to a stack overflow.

```
public class RoleCUViewModel
{
    private string? _name;

    [Required]
    public string? Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value != "Admin")
            {
                _name = value;
            }
            else _name = null;
        }
    }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```